# ScrollPanel with slim scrollbar?

Tags: java, javascript, html, css, gwt

I want to extend the [GWT ScrollPanel](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/ScrollPanel.html) to modify the scrollbar for this panel.

I would do it like:

```
public class MyScrollPanel extends ScrollPanel {

    public MyScrollPanel() {
        super();        
    }

}
```

The scrollbar should look like this:

[image]

(Source: http://rocha.la/jQuery-slimScroll)

**How can I modify the GWT ScrollPanel that the scrollbar looks like in the image above?**

Comment: Can you please elaborate what you have done for this. What exact problem is.

Comment: My Problem is that I do not how to start to make the scroll bar overlapping the content.

Comment: The simple answer is use z-index css property keeping the scroll bar position absolute. More over I don't think one could help without seeing what is done

Comment: @UmeshA how do I change the z-index of the scrollbar?